# Is there any UpToDate possible way to transform PDF/DocX into Text via Javascript

Tags: javascript, docx, pdf-reader, pdftotext

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var myResume = document.getElementById('myResume');
    var displayResume = document.getElementById('displayResume');

    myResume.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        var resume = myResume.files[0];
        var textType = /text.*/;
        var imageType = /image.*/;

        if (resume.type.match(textType)) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                displayResume.innerText = reader.result;
            }
            reader.readAsText(resume);
        }
        else if (resume.type.match(imageType)) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                displayResume.innerHTML = "";
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = reader.result;
                var string = OCRAD(img);
                alert(string);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(resume);
        }
        else if (myResume.files[0].type === 'application/pdf') {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                displayResume.innerHTML = "";
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = reader.result;
                Tesseract.recognize(img)
                    .progress(function  (p) { console.log('progress', p)    })
                    .then(function (result) { console.log('result', result) })
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(resume);
        }
        else if (myResume.files[0].type === 'application/msword') {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                displayResume.innerHTML = "";
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = reader.result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(resume);
        }
        else
            displayResume.innerText = "Media type couldn't recognized.";
    });
}

$("#submitBTN").click(function() {
    if ( (myResume.files.length == 0) && (myCover.files.length == 0) )
        alert ("No files uploaded.");
});
```

```css
.centralize {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 250px;
}
#displayResume {
  margin-top: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.header-title {
    float: none !important;
    color: #FFF !important;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar-header {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="text/html">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">  
    <meta name="robots" content="all,follow">
    <title>Arete Human Resources</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand header-title">Arete Human Resources</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="container centralize">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
                <input type="file" id="myResume" accept=".txt,.doc,.docx,.pdf,.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" ng-model="fileName" placeholder="Your name here">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <h4>{{fileName}}</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
                <input type="file" id="myCover" accept=".txt,.doc,.docx,.pdf,.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" ng-model="fileDesc" placeholder="Explanations">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <h5>{{fileDesc}}</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <button type="submit" class="button button-outline button-positive" id="submitBTN" onclick="" style="float:right">Submit</button>
        <div id="displayResume"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/ionic.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/ionic.bundle.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/ionic-angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/ocrad.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--<script src="js/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    <script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js/1.0.10/dist/tesseract.js'></script>
    <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to get input file from user and try to change the file into text and send later whatever user sends as input. I thought main inputs as either text, pdf, docx and even image.

I found out [ocrad](http://antimatter15.com/ocrad.js/demo.html) for `image` and it works perfect, hence for `pdf/docx` it never worked somehow even if I tried with [pdfreader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfreader), [pdf-to-text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-to-text), [composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md), [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js), [docxtemplater](https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater), [study.js](http://www.studyjs.com/javascript/pdf.html), and many others as well. I tried to add libraries as usual on terminal with `node` and even I debugged, I couldn't find a way. Here is  the [codePen](http://codepen.io/erhanyasar/pen/jyjdWb) and below is the snippet and I'd be glad if someone approve an existing library working already at the present time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if this was not clearly explained in the documentation, but [pdfreader](https://github.com/adrienjoly/npm-pdfreader) is meant to be run on node.js, not in a web browser. Hence the `require` problem.

Here is how to convert your PDF résumé into text, from Node.js:

```
var pdfreader = require('pdfreader');

var rows = {}; // indexed by y-position

function printRows() {
  Object.keys(rows) // => array of y-positions (type: float)
    .sort((y1, y2) => parseFloat(y1) - parseFloat(y2)) // sort float positions
    .forEach((y) => console.log((rows[y] || []).join('')));
}

new pdfreader.PdfReader().parseFileItems('CV_ErhanYasar.pdf', function(err, item){
  if (!item || item.page) {
    // end of file, or page
    printRows();
    console.log('PAGE:', item.page);
    rows = {}; // clear rows for next page
  }
  else if (item.text) {
    // accumulate text items into rows object, per line
    (rows[item.y] = rows[item.y] || []).push(item.text);
  }
});
```

=> Then, that's the output you're gonna get:

[image: example cv resume parse convert pdf to text]

Comment: Well thanks anyway, I couldn't find anyone to answer any of my concerns yet. There is a couple of things I'm still not sure;

First, you imply that I can't use it (it doesn't work even if I do) with the browser's javascript, right?

Secondly, if I want to use it with node.js how can I configure the app above  to get the related users file/document?

And last (if I'm still not able to do it with your library), do you know or suggest any way to do it in user's browser side?

Well, very much thanks if u can specify a bit any of them.

Comment: It really depends on the type of content of your PDF files (input). Are there tables? Plain text? Graphics?

Comment: You could get more help if your needs were more specific, and you provided a sample PDF to convert.

Comment: They'll all be `plain texts`, consisting of resumes or cover letters. I even don't care if even they include complex data. I used [my own CV](http://www.erhanyasar.com.tr/files/CV_ErhanYasar.pdf) with `pdf.js` but it gave an encrypted text consisting of square characters somehow.

Comment: On how to do it directly on the browser: I don't know. I would have the conversion process happen on a node.js server, and the web client make requests to that server.

Comment: If you send me a sample input PDF document that you don't mind sharing online (i.e. to provide as example on pdfreader's github page), I can propose to send you the pdfreader-based code needed to convert it. :-)

Comment: I shared the link above to [my CV](http://www.erhanyasar.com.tr/files/CV_ErhanYasar.pdf) and I appreciate if you provide anything or direct me to do so.

Comment: Thanks, @ErhanYaşar! Can you confirm that you give me permission to publish your CV as an example of use, on npmreader's github page? In return to that, you'd have a working script to parse your CV.

Comment: Sure! Hell yeah 

Comment: Ok, @ErhanYaşar ! I'm going to do it now, live on Twitch and LiveEdu, if you're interested: http://adrienjoly.com/livecoding/

Comment: @ErhanYaşar I made two simple parsing scripts based on npmreader, to parse your CV: https://github.com/adrienjoly/npm-pdfreader-example => does that solve your problem?

Comment: Besides thanking you so much, since my main purpose in the question itself to ask reading pdf/documents browser-side, I'll leave the question still unanswered and not sure yet if anyway exists. Lacking a solution for transforming any kind of file into text via browser-side lead me to turn this gap into product also with the example you provided me (I'll be notifying you with the credentials). Furthermore, I need more clarification with the example's 3 different `.js` files and kindly ask you to share the `recorded` link to live coding session (it's expired).

Comment: Well, now I understand that `parseRows.js` is to transform into plain text and `parseTable.js` for displaying as a table text. I didn't got what `parseItems.js` was for at first sight, but now it's ok; that's for just check I guess.

Comment: @ErhanYaşar you can find the video recordings on this page: https://www.twitch.tv/adrienjoly/videos/all. I wish you best of luck to do this from your web browser! :-) Please share your solution here when you find one!

Comment: tx again, I'll let you know whenever find a way or unleash a way to workaround instead all that stuff. I'll be following you for your works, wish you more success!

Comment: Can it read texts in images inside the PDF?

Comment: @holydragon no, it has no OCR.